# Two proofs of the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations - one correct, one not?

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

> **Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus of Variations.**
>   Let $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ and
>   $$
> \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \varphi(x) dx = 0 \quad
> \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\text{c}}(a,b).
> $$
>   Then, we have $u|_{(a,b)} \equiv 0$ almost everywhere.

I am going to present the proof our professor did and the one I found in the lecture notes from the same course a few years back. 
I would like to know if both approaches are correct or the first is not because it ignores some details or if the second proof is just unnecessarily complicated.

**Proof 1:**
Let $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ a compact interval with $c < d$.
We aim to show $\int_{c}^{d} | u(x) | dx = 0$, which yields the claim since $[c,d]$ was chosen arbitrarily.
Define $\omega := \text{sgn}(u) \cdot \chi_{[c,d]}$.
Furthermore, define $\omega_{\varepsilon} := \omega \star J_{\varepsilon}$ ($\star$ = convolution), where
$$
J_{\varepsilon}(x)
:= \begin{cases} c_{\varepsilon}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}\right), & | x | < 1, \\
0, & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
and $c_{\varepsilon}$ is chosen such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} J_{\varepsilon}(x) dx = 1$.

In a previous lemma we have shown that

1. for sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\omega_{\varepsilon} \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\text{c}}(a,b)$ and
2. $\omega_{\varepsilon} \xrightarrow{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \omega$ almost everywhere on $(a,b)$.

We now want to use Lebesgue's theorem to show
\begin{equation*}
\int_{a}^{b} \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) u(x)
= \int_{c}^{d} | u(x) | dx
= 0.
\end{equation*} 
To find a integrable majorant for $\omega_{\varepsilon}$ we observe that
\begin{equation*}
| \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) |
= \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} J_{\varepsilon}(x - \xi) \omega_{\varepsilon}(\xi) d\xi \right|
\le \max_{\xi \in \mathbb{R}} | \omega_{\varepsilon}(\xi) |  \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}} J_{\varepsilon}(x - \xi) d \xi
= 1 \cdot 1
= 1.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $| u(x) \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) | \le | u(x) |$.

Because $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ we have $u \in L^1(c,d)$ and therefore, $| u |$ is a integrable majorant for $u \omega_{\varepsilon}$. $\square$

**Proof 2**
    Let $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ and $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$.
    Define $\omega = \text{sgn}(u) \chi_{[c,d]}$.
    Then we have $\omega \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ and $\text{supp}(\omega) \subset [c,d]$.

*!The $\tilde{J}_{\varepsilon}$ is the $J_{\varepsilon}$ from above!*

Now define $\omega_{\varepsilon} :=  \tilde{J}_{\varepsilon} \ast \omega$.
    Then, $\omega_{\varepsilon} \to \omega$ almost everywhere on $(a,b)$ and $\text{supp}(\omega_{\varepsilon}) \subset [c - \varepsilon, d + \varepsilon]$, hence $\omega_{\varepsilon} \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\text{c}}(a,b)$ if $\varepsilon$ is small enough.

We obtain
    \begin{align*}
  0
  = \int_{a}^{b} \underbrace{u(x) \omega_{\varepsilon}(x)}_{\xrightarrow{\textrm{a.e.}}  u(x) \omega(x)} dx
  & = \int_{c - \varepsilon}^{d + \varepsilon} u(x)  \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) dx \\
  & = \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \chi_{[c - \varepsilon, d + \varepsilon]}(x) \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) dx.
 \end{align*}
    As 
    \begin{equation*}
  | \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) |
  \le \int \tilde{J}_{\varepsilon}(x - y) \underbrace{| \omega(y) |}_{\le 1} dy
  \le 1,
 \end{equation*}
For $\varepsilon_0 < \min(c - a, b - d)$ and all $\varepsilon < \varepsilon_0$ we get
    \begin{equation*}
  | u(x) \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) |
  \le | u(x) | \chi_{[c - \varepsilon_0, d + \varepsilon_0]}(x)
 \end{equation*}
    This function is integrable on $(a,b)$.
    Therefore, Lebesgues theorem shows
    \begin{equation*}
  0
  = \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \omega(x) dx
  = \int_{c}^{d} | u(x) | dx,
 \end{equation*}
    hence $u \equiv 0$ almost everywhere on $[c,d]$.
    As $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ was chosen arbitrarily, this yields the claim. $\square$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both proofs are fine, although there is a limit missing in the first one, it should say
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{a}^{b} \omega_{\varepsilon}(x) u(x)
= \int_{c}^{d} | u(x) | dx
= 0.
\end{equation*}
and the definition of $\omega$ is wrong, it should be 
$$\omega(x) := \text{sgn}(u(x))\chi_{[c,d]}(x).$$
The main difference between the proofs is this: the second proof contains an argument why $\text{supp}(\omega_{\epsilon}) \subseteq (a,b)$ for $\epsilon$ small enough, while in the first proof they argue this point by referring to a "previous lemma".